# Qt permanent thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to create a qt thread which is permanently running next to the UI thread and performs work on demand or is idle. What is the correct way to implement a qt thread which is not performing some work and ending then, but is active unil the app is closed? Can anyone link sample code?
I have Qt 5, C++

I found a sample here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html (Example 4) but I dont know how the WorkerObject class should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done by a *thread pool*. Not a single thread.

Comment: My thread should contain several functions to perform different jobs. is thread pool suitable? if yes, can anyone link a good sample?

Comment: @wildcat: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html#example-1-using-the-thread-pool

Comment: So, yes, it's possible. The threadpool may decide to use two threads, if it believes that's more efficient.